# Url is encoded in UTF-8 but Python is trying to read it as cp1256

Tags: python, windows, request, cp1252

I am trying to run this code:

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('https://www.binance.com/assetWithdraw/getAllAsset.html')
print(resp.json())
```

But I get this ouput in my command prompt:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0e3f' in 
position 2666: character maps to <undefined>
```

The url I am trying to read is in UTF-8 but the python is trying to read cp1252. Is there any way of getting python to use utf8.py instead of cp1252.py??

PS, a buddy of mine can run this code flawlessly on his MAC. Is this more of a windows issue rather than python?

Comment: This is working for me fine

Comment: @Simon This works for me on python3. I got a huge response from the get.

Comment: @Simon Are you both using a mac? A buddy of mine is running it flawlessly as well. Only difference is that he is using a mac and I am using Windows.

Comment: @PurexedPose  Nope I'm on Windows running Python 3.6 (if you are running 2.7 that might explain it)

Comment: @Simon, thats so odd. Im running 3.5

Comment: just upgraded it to python 3.6 and it worked!!

Comment: Also works for me (Python 2.7.15, windows 10)

Comment: The `get` line is probably not the problem, I'm guessing its the `print(resp.json())` line, you're trying to print unicode data to a terminal that doesn't understand unicode.

Comment: If the full stack trace were included, the error is generated from the `print` and it matters what IDE or terminal is being used for the output.  Pre-Python 3.6 encodes Unicode strings in the output terminal encoding.  The OP's environment is using cp1252 for output.  That encoding only supports a subset of Unicode (256 characters vs. millions).  If using an IDE with UTF-8 encoding as the default, that encoding supports all of Unicode.  So user experience will vary.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure a string's unicode is correctly converted you can use [the unidecode module](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/)

Here however, python thinks you have a special character in your string ('`\u0e3f`' is the Unicode Character 'THAI CURRENCY SYMBOL BAHT',[image]

Can you try the following?: **retype your code to a new python file**  (**DO NOT copy-paste**) and retry. This might have to do with one of the characters being different than what you think (e.g. the A in getAllAsset might be greek A etc.) Some times the sting your editor displays and that you think is stored, is not what you think. It just looks the same /the diference is invisible in your editor and this can be a devil to debug...

Answer (score 0):

The JSON retrieved is correct and the problem has nothing to do with the URL retrieval or the JSON conversion.  The problem is the terminal output via `print`.  Pre-Python 3.6 printing Unicode strings to a terminal encodes the output in the terminal's encoding on Windows, hence the `UnicodeEncodeError`.  For example, the US Windows command prompt defaults to `cp437`:

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 437
```

In pre-Python 3.6, printing a Unicode string to the terminal fails if characters outside the code page are used.  Note that it is attempting to use the terminal's active code page:

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\N{EURO SIGN}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u20ac' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

In Python 3.6, printing a character on Windows uses the console Unicode APIs, and ignores the code page:

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\N{EURO SIGN}')
€
```

To bypass the encoding error, on Python 3.x, you can `print(ascii(resp.json()))` to see that the response is correct.  Python 2.x you can use `print repr(resp.json())`.  Both only display ASCII characters and non-ASCII is printed as escape codes.

```
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print repr(u'\N{EURO SIGN}')
u'\u20ac'
```